# What is the significance of the number 9,223,372,036,854,775,295

Tags: binary, numbers, long-integer

So I was trying to find out the maximum possible value of `$limit` aggregation pipeline operator in `mongodb 3.4`.

By trying out some combinations, I found out the maximum allowed value for `$limit` stage is `9223372036854775295`, so I was wondering what is the significance of this number?

Also, I did check `2^63` comes out to be `9223372036854775808`, which while VERY close to `9223372036854775295`, the numbers do have a difference of `513`, so I was wondering what the significance of this number is.

Comment: the maximum value of a 64-bit signed integer is 2^63-1, so the real difference is 512 which is 2^9

Comment: I noticed that, but what i dont understand is why does that difference exist between the values. If thats due to some memory limitations or something else.